# Datatable ajax calling from php page

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to load json from my php page into a Datatable with the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#detailed').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "myphpPage.php",
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        "columns": [{
            data: "SEG_CODE"
        }, {
            data: "START_MOMENT"
        }, {
            data: "STOP_MOMENT"
        }]
    });
});
```

The json doesn't show up in the Datatable instead all I see is "Loading..."

When I copy the json payload from my php page and save to to a txt doc and call that doc instead the json is showing no problem in the Datatable:

```
$('#detailed').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "detailed.txt",
        "dataSrc": "data"
    },
    "columns": [{
        data: "SEG_CODE"
    }, {
        data: "START_MOMENT"
    }, {
        data: "STOP_MOMENT"
    }]
});
```

Here's my json array:

```
{"data":[{"SEG_CODE":"FDTOT","START_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 09:00:00","STOP_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 17:00:00"},{"SEG_CODE":"PBRK1","START_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 11:00:00","STOP_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 11:15:00"},{"SEG_CODE":"UBRK1","START_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 13:00:00","STOP_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 13:30:00"},{"SEG_CODE":"PBRK2","START_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 15:45:00","STOP_MOMENT":"2015-09-21 16:00:00"}]}
```

Is there a reason why from my php page the datatable gets stuck at loading and not with the txt doc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you call json from remote?

Comment: try use only "ajax": "myphpPage.php", without dataSrc and check request in debug tool what return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@daremachine, thanks, I entered full url instead of relative.

changed:

```
"url": "www.mysite/myphpPage.php",
```

to:

```
"url": "./myphpPage.php",
```